# Avoid querying related tables in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

The model:

```
class RegistrationSlot(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name="Event", to=Event, related_name="registrations", on_delete=CASCADE)
    hole = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name="Hole", to=Hole, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    registration = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name="Registration", to=Registration, blank=True, null=True,
                                     on_delete=SET_NULL, related_name="slots")
    player = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name="Player", to=Player, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    starting_order = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Starting order", default=0)
    slot = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Slot number", default=0)
    status = models.CharField(verbose_name="Status", choices=STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=1, default="A")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("hole", "slot")
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=["event", "player"], name="unique_player_registration")
        ]

    objects = RegistrationSlotManager()
```

In the manager I declare that I always want the player:

```
class RegistrationSlotManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().select_related("player")
```

The primary access pattern for this data is to query by an event id, so the view filter looks like this:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = RegistrationSlot.objects.all()
        event_id = self.request.query_params.get("event_id", None)

        if event_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(event=event_id)
        return queryset
```

And what my UI wants is very simple. The serialized json object does not include related objects other than the player:

```
    {
        "id": 5798,
        "event": 344,
        "hole": 1,
        "registration": 9996,
        "starting_order": 0,
        "slot": 0,
        "status": "R",
        "player": {
            "id": 353,
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Dough"
        }
    }
```

So while trying to optimize my api, this query should be one of the fastest, but it's not. The Django ORM is generating 1000+ queries that I do not want. The register_registrationslot query below returns all the data I need. But Django is grabbing related event data and its related data. Maybe this is because of the unique constraint or the filter by event id?
[image: query-output]

This seems like it should be simple to optimize, but I cannot find the docs that explain if I am able to provide a hint that says "Do not follow the related objects" or something like that.

Is there a built-in way to get what I want, or will I have to revert to custom SQL?

Comment: It looks like you are processing something with a `Course` model, but that is not included in the view you show here.

Comment: Course is off the event model. The event model is fairly complex, but it is also pretty static, so it responds well to caching. The caller (the UI) already has the full event model in state.

Comment: then why is each query done 9 times, and all queries on the `Course` model 45 times?

Comment: An event can have many courses. A course can have many holes. I haven't optimized the event queries yet because that's a low priority. Regardless of how all the event data is fetched, for the model in question, I don't need any of it.

Comment: Do you test is via some lovely graphic interface for api generated by additional package? Can you try testing via curl / talend api tester?

Comment: Yes, and apparently that is exactly the problem -- the UI of debug_toolbar is causing more data to be selected. I switched over to logging from `django.db.backends` and the queries look as I would expect.

Comment: The debug toolbar should only show queries that the application has executed. It does not execute additional queries unless you click SELECT or EXPLAIN. What does the toolbar indicate as the culprit of the issue? If this does end up being a DDT issue, please create an issue: github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/